# What are reasons for a notificaton to be dismissed or cancelled?

Tags: android, notifications

which APIs or system events can cause a notification to be disabled, other that `NotificationManager.cancel()` or `NotificationManager.cancelAll()`?

Context:
I'm debugging a service, that is running in the foreground and therefore must display a notification. I update that notification using `NotificationManager.notify()` at regular intervals with appropriate information.

However, following a sequence of reproducable steps, the Notification will revert to a system placeholder text "[App Name] started - Processes running in the background".

I've isolated every instance of `NotificationManager.cancel()` or `NotificationManager.cancelAll()` and they are not called, when the notification reverts. I should note, that this problem only surfaces on a Nexus 7 with KitKat, but not on a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2.

Comment: If you call NotificationManager.notify() with the same identifier the notification will be updated. You have set a id different from 0?

Comment: Yes, the notification id is != 0 defined in res/values/ids.xml. The same ID is used to set the service to foreground as well as the subsequent updates.